# left join table name dynmicly form the main query

Tags: mysql

I have a `bills` table with `column customer_type` and `customer_id` fields.

This `customer_type` tells if the customer is in the `customers` table or in the `users` table or in the `suppliers` table.

I need to create a query with left join according to `customer_type`.

```
select c.* from bills b 
left join ***b.customer_type*** c on c.id = b.customer_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join all three with necessary condition:

```
select c.*, u.*, s.* from bills b 
left join customers c on c.id = b.customer_id and b.customer_type = 'customers'
left join users u on u.id = b.customer_id and b.customer_type = 'users'
left join suppliers s on s.id = b.customer_id and b.customer_type = 'suppliers'
```

Then you can take the data that is relevant from the result.

However if there are similar columns in these 3 tables you might want to restructure the database to only store one type of information in one place.